# Can I do an install onto a 4GB usb stick which is smaller than the recommended installation size?

Tags: installation, usb-drive

I've read through this question:

[How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

So I am aware how to install Ubuntu onto a USB stick.

I'm also aware that the minimum recommended HDD requirement for ubuntu is 5GB.

- my question is specifically, can I squeeze the install of Ubuntu 11.10 onto a 4GB usb stick?

Can I do so without downloading alternate version of Ubuntu? Because I have only two 4GB usb sticks available.

All I want is

- firefox
- wi-fi

What I have

- live USB of Ubuntu 11.10
- notebook without hdd
- internet access
- 4GB usb stick

The reason why I need full install is to **install new programs** (skype) and do **upgrade** (of flash player)

Comment: Installing Lubuntu - the lightweight version of Ubuntu - can be done on a 4GB USB. Please see [this forum post.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1872303)